# MSP430 "Unknown Device" vs "Security Fuse blown" Error in MSP-Flasher

Tags: microcontroller

Update. After half day googling. I read the following at
https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp-low-power-microcontrollers-group/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/904250/msp430g2403-how-to-check-the-fuse-is-formally-blown-with-launchpad

"Hi support,

I am working on MSP430 G2 family, and I would like to check formally if the fuse is blown. I have only the LaunchPad programmer board, but with this board, and the TI win32 application MSP430Flasher.exe, there is no formal check to distinguish whether the fuse is really blown or the hardware setting is not correct. It gives basically the same error. Deeper verification can be done on some hardware as Replicator with function IsFuseBlown() but this seems to be not supported by LaunchPad embedded firmware.

IsFuseBlown()verify that TDI signal is returned on TDO delayed by one TCK pulse, and so giving high confidence that fuse is really blown and MCI is not out of order or hardware setup is incorrect for this verification. I precise that the MSP430 target is already on PCB and I cannot rely on operation done before."

Also
https://www.ti.com/lit/slau320

[image]

Question: Is IsFuseBlown()verify mentioned above implemented in the Msp-Fet430UIF and Msp Flasher? I cant participate at the TI site because I dont have company account there.

Original message:

When JTAG fuse has been blown in MSP430 MCUs. There is no longer any access to JTAG. How does the MSP-Flasher know whether security fuse has been blown in the MCU in intact device versus not able to detect the device (or unknown device). I tried MSP-Flasher and got this error:

[image]

The following is from the user manual showing the screenshot of "Security fuse has been blown".
In other words, when security fuse has been blown, all JTAG access was lost, so how could MSP-Flasher know if there is still an MCU and show error "Security fuse has been blown". Is it not the same as "Unknown device" since it can't detect the MCU presence because of lack of JTAG access?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a subtle difference, the manual shows v1.2.0 which displays a disconnect message, which your attempt using v1.3.20 does not. Try to get the same flasher revision and repeat - maybe they only changed the text message for this situation...

Comment: The answers to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/114739/326463) might be interesting to you. Small chance to revive your device...

Comment: I know blowing the JTAG fuse means you can no longer access it but only via BSL. I'm trying to find out if the chip is blown but how does one know if it is really blown or only incorrect access resulting in same "unknown device", unless there is a way to distinguished between real blown fuse and incorrect connections?   also i can't find older msp flasher version v1.2.0. It's only v1.3.20 at the ti site. Where to get the older version?

Comment: Well, checking continuity of connections is possible, and you can know if there is something else these wires. Being in a hurry therewith renders any effort via BSL potentialky useless. At last, if BSL works, you're the lucky one, if not the MSP is busted. Testing BSL procedure on a know good part may be wise.

Comment: Its a working MCU module. I just want to know if the JTAG fuse was blown already. How do I differentiate between the fuse really blown or the interface just connected wrong?

Comment: You probably can't differentiate it. Just connect it right ;-)

Comment: It seems there might be ways to distinguish. Lets wait for those who have encountered it to give definite answer.